# How to achieve this substring?

Tags: php

There is a string having a dot form like this : `1.1.3`

I want to get the `substring` of this string from the beginning untill the position of the last "." - 1 , that is `1.1` .

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$versionstring = "1.1.3";

echo substr($versionstring,0,strrpos($versionstring,"."));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mb_substr($string,0,strpos($string, "."));
```